# What should I call this utility function? Is something like it commonly used?

Tags: algorithms, javascript

Suppose you want to combine some arrays of objects that have similar properties:

```
var people = [{name: 'Jack', age: 10}, {name: 'Jill', age: 12}]
var items = [{owner: 'Jack', name: 'pail'}, {owner: 'Jill', name: 'water'}]

var output = process(people, items)
//  [{name: 'Jack', age: 10, items: ['pail']},
//   {name: 'Jack', age: 12, items: ['water']}]
```

It could easily be done with a nested loop:

```
var process = people => people.map(p => ({
  ...p,
  items: p.items.concat(items.find(i => i.owner === p.name))}))
```

This has complexity `O(people * items)` which is fine for such a trivial example but might not scale.

You may want to filter one array by another:

```
var items = [{id: 5, name: 'John'}, {id: 8, name: 'Jordan'}, {id: 16, name: 'Josephine'}]
var ids = [5, 16]

var output = process(items, ids)
//  [{id: 5, name: 'John'}, {id: 16, name: 'Josephine'}]
```

Which could be done with a similar approach, and would take a similar ammount of time.

The complexity for these kind of problems can be improved from `O(a0 * a1 * a2...)` to `O((a0 + a1 + a2...) * log(a0 + a1 + a2...))` by sorting all the arrays, padding missing values, zipping and then iterating once through the result:

```
var items = [{id: 5, name: 'John'}, {id: 8, name: 'Jordan'}, {id: 16, name: 'Josephine'}]
var ids = [5, 16]

var result = preProcess(items, ids, v => v.id || v)
//  [[{id: 5, name: 'John'}, {id: 8, name: 'Jordan'}, {id: 16, name: 'Josephine'}],
//   [5, undefined, 16]]

result = zip(result)
//  [[{id: 5, name: 'John'}, 5],
//   [{id: 8, name: 'Jordan'}, undefined],
//   [{id: 16, name: 'Josephine'}, 16]]

result = result.filter(([item, id]) => id).map(([item]) => item)
//  [{id: 5, name: 'John'}, {id: 16, name: 'Josephine'}]
```

This works great for me and fixed some performance issues in a game. But I've never seen this approach in the wild, is there a better way? If not, does this way have a name? There's plenty of places it could be used.

You could alternatively (not necessarily w/ many arrays) sort one array and use bisection search for the inner loop. Is this what programmers normally do instead?

This is my implementation of `preProcess` for the curious:

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import _f from 'lodash/fp'

const _preProcess = (arrs, f) => {
  const result = []
  const indexes = arrs.map(() => 0) // resultIndex, currentIndex
  const sorted = arrs.map(_.flow(_f.map(v => [f(v), v]), _f.sortBy('0')))
  while (indexes.find((v, i) => sorted[i].length - 1 >= v) !== undefined) {
    let values = sorted.map((a, i) => a[indexes[i]])
    const min = _.minBy(values, '0')[0]
    values = values.map(([fv, v], i) => fv === min ? (indexes[i] += 1, v) : undefined)
    result.push(values)
  }
  return _.zip(...result)
}

const preProcess = (...args) =>
  _preProcess(
    args.length === 2 ? args[0] : args.slice(0, -1),
    _.chain(args).last().iteratee().value())
```

Comment: In the context of JavaScript, I'd imagine most people would simply do, in pseudo-code, `dict = {}; foreach(item in items){dict[item.id] = item;}; result = ids.map(id => dict[id]);` What you are doing (and my version as well) is akin to indexing in a database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the operations you're doing are variations of [SQL joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join), 
because in most cases you're taking tuples of data, picking a kind of value from each one to associate, and returning the combination(s) that could be linked.

I'd suggest you look into the jargon, algorithms, and research-papers of RDBMs systems as your first place to mine for more information. I mean, consider what an SQL [query-planner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_plan) has to do: It takes a high-level description of what the user wants to achieve, estimates the sizes of the data-sets involved, checks if useful indexes exist, and chooses a series of [many algorithmic steps](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/zones/informix/library/techarticle/0206metzger/0206metzger3.html) to chain together in order to get fast and accurate result.

> You may want to filter one array by another:
>
> ```
> var items = [{id: 5, name: 'John'}, {id: 8, name: 'Jordan'}, {id: 16, name: 'Josephine'}]
> var ids = [5, 16]
>
> var output = process(items)
> //  [{id: 5, name: 'John'}, {id: 16, name: 'Josephine'}]
> ```

... Join on ID?

> ```
> var people = [{name: 'Jack', age: 10}, {name: 'Jill', age: 12}]
> var items = [{owner: 'Jack', name: 'pail'}, {owner: 'Jill', name: 'water'}]
>
> var output = process(people, items)
> //  [{name: 'Jack', age: 10, items: ['pail']},
> //   {name: 'Jack', age: 12, items: ['water']}]
> ```

... Join on owner, with grouping by owner and aggregation of (item-)name?